# Android context

Tags: android, io, android-context

I 'm reading on how to write to internal storage, and found the following code methods on the Android Developer forum.

In both the the cases, I do not know how to get/invoke the "context"'s method.

I don't understand what the context variable is and how I can create one.

Say I want app read a file on start up.

What is context and how can I use it to achieve reading from storage.

> File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);

```
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("Data.dat",
                                                 Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
```

Comment: take look on this thread , will help you to understand the context in android , and feed me back 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android

Comment: When I tried to get the context via `Context context = this` the `.openFileInput` gives me an error of "The method openFileInput(String) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)"

Comment: openFileInput  this method take only the name of the file you need to open  but this method openFileOutput take two arguments file name and the mode

Answer (score 1):

Android Developer site's Documentation about File reading from internal storage says...

> To read a file from internal storage:
>
> 1. Call `openFileInput()` and pass it the name of the file to read. This returns a `FileInputStream`.
> 2. Read bytes from the file with `read()`.
> 3. Then close the stream with `close()`.

So, your code to read the file named `Data.dat` should be as below.

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("Data.dat");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```